# React and Browserify Register Component Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify

I am using browserify, gulp and reactjs together,

I have the following `app.js` contains my other scripts;

```
var React = window.React = require('react');
var Signup = require('./ui/Signup');
var Login = require('./ui/Login');
```

`Signup.js``

```
var React = require('react');
var signupNode = document.getElementById('signup');

var SignupApp = React.createClass({
render: function(){
    return (<Signup/>)
   }
});

var Signup = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
    return (
            <div>
                <div classNameName="form-block center-block">
                    <h2 classNameName="title">Üye Ol</h2>
                    <SignupForm/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
   }
});

var SignupForm = React.createClass({
render: function(){
    return (<div className='form-horizontal'>
                hede
            </div>)
   }
});

React.renderComponent(<SignupApp/>, signupNode);
module.exports = Signup;
```

and Login.js

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var React = require('react');
var loginNode = document.getElementById("login");


var LoginApp = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (<Login></Login>)
    }

});

var Login = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
                <div>
                    <div className="form-block center-block">
                        <h2 className="title">Giriş Yap</h2>
                        <LoginForm/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                            )
    }
});





var LoginForm = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (<div className="form-horizontal">
                    hede
                </div>
        )
    }
});
React.renderComponent(<LoginApp/>, loginNode);

module.exports = Login
```

I want those modules to be ready according to their dom elements for different templates which i am both including app.js,

But I am having `Invalid Violation Register Component` `Target container is not a DOM element.` error because Login Modal can not find signup id on DOM. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you loading the scripts at end end of the BODY of the HTML? You'll need to delay execution of the script until the DOM element is ready.

Comment: Login and Signup are different template files both including app.js, scripts are at the end of the body, is there a smart way to render Signup component only on Signup template

Comment: I don't follow -- the HTML element **does** exist? If the scripts are being initialized after the main document body has been loaded, then `document.getElementById` will work for any element that exists in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed, when i made a custom routing like below;

```
if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('login') > -1) {
    React.renderComponent(<Login/>, loginNode);
}
if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('signup') > -1) {
    React.renderComponent(<Signup/>, signupNode);
}
if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('new_post') > -1) {
    React.renderComponent(<NewPost/>, newPostNode);
}
if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('home') > -1) {
    React.renderComponent(<Home/>, HomeNode);
}
```