# React.js renderDOM conditionally

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React. I have some issue on render with reactDom:

**index.js**

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import A from 'components/A';
import B from 'components/B';

render(<A />, document.getElementById('A'));
render(<B />, document.getElementById('B'));
```

I want to show something like

- render A to page A
- render B to page B
  The problem is when I define A and B together on index.js, so on page A (not have elementId B here), it will show error like below because React doesn't have elementId B on page A

  Invalid Violation Register Component Target container is not a DOM element

Checking by path like [React and Browserify Register Component Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29198714/react-and-browserify-register-component-error/29330098#29330098) can fix it too, or checking `elementid`(exists or not) before calling `render`.

I'd like to know if this is the right way to solve case like this, or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if (document.getElementById('A')) {
    render(<A />, document.getElementById('A'));
}

if (document.getElementById('B')) {
    render(<B />, document.getElementById('B'));
}
```

This is the simplest and easiest solution to your problem (it's not the cleanest nor the best solution but it is easiest to understand when learning React and how it works with the DOM).  It will not render `<A />` if it cannot find `A` container, and it will not render `<B />` if it cannot find `B` container.